# Twilio - can't process phone number after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I'm following this link for the tutorial (via [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/verify-sms-express#:%7E:text=Many%20applications%20verify%20and%20authorize,call%20or%20a%20text%20message).) and have followed all the
required steps but when I run the localhost and input a number, I get no text message, nor does the window for verification open. It just stays at the same page of "enter your phone number".

[image: Screenshot of page]

Here's my HTML code

```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <HTML>
      <head>

    <title>Verify SMS Demo</title>
    <style>
        #verify-form,
        #response-text {
            display: none;
        }
     </style>
     </head>

    <body>
    <form id="phone-form">
        <h2>Enter your phone number with country code:</h2>
        <input type="tel" id="phone-number-input" placeholder="15551235555" />
        <input id="phone-submit" type="submit" />
    </form>

    <form id="verify-form">
        <h2>Enter your verification code:</h2>
        <input type="number" id="otp-input" placeholder="e.g. 123456" />
        <input id="verify-submit" type="submit" />
    </form>

    <div id="response-text"></div>
     </body>

     <script type="text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
    </html>`
```

And here's my code for script.js:

```js
    const phoneForm = document.getElementById('phone-form');
    const verifyForm = document.getElementById('verify-form');
    const responseText = document.getElementById('response-text');

    let phoneNumber;

    phoneForm.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phone-number-input').value;

      const response = await fetch('/send-notification', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({phoneNumber : phoneNumber })
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));

      if (response.ok) {
        phoneForm.style.display = 'none';
        verifyForm.style.display = 'block';
      }
    });

    verifyForm.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const otp = document.getElementById('otp-input').value;

      const data = { 
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber, 
        otp: top
      };

      const response = await fetch('/verify-otp', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));

      const check = await response.json();

      const text = response.ok ? check.status : response.statusText;
      responseText.innerHTML = text;

      verifyForm.style.display = 'none';
      responseText.style.display = 'block';  
    });
```

EDIT Here is my index.js file:

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    require('dotenv').config();
    const client = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(express.json()); 
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/index.html'));
    });
    
    app.post('/send-verification', async (req, res) => {
      client.verify.services(verify)
        .verifications
        .create({to: `+${req.body.phoneNumber}`, channel: 'sms'})
        .then(verification => console.log(verification.status))
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
          res.status(500).send(e);
        });
    
      res.sendStatus(200);
    });
    
    app.post('/verify-otp', async (req, res) => {
      const check = await client.verify.services(verify)
        .verificationChecks
        .create({to: `+${req.body.phoneNumber}`, code: req.body.otp})
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
          res.status(500).send(e);
        });
    
      res.status(200).send(check);
    });
    
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Comment: Take a look at the browser devtools, (right click on the web page, click inspect, then click on the console tab). Then retry, and see if the error helps you identify the issue. It could be your backend code (Express) is not running.

Comment: Do you see any errors from your express application where it is running in the terminal?

Comment: I used inspect element and got "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" referring /send-notification. But I copied it directly from the tutorial so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: @philnash I also don't get any errors from the terminal when running the application

Comment: Are you running the express application side of things? Can you share your index.js code?

Comment: Yes I have the express dependency installed. I also added my index.js file @philnash

Answer (score 0):

Your front-end is making a request to `/send-notification` but your application end point is at `/send-verification`.

Update your front-end code to:

```js
      const response = await fetch('/send-verification', {
```

and you should be good to go.

**Edit**

Now, in the server you are getting the error:

```
sh-3.2$ node index.js Server started at localhost:3000
/Users/username/Downloads/keep_out-3/verify-sms-express/index.js:17
  client.verify.services(verify)
                         ^ ReferenceError: verify is not defined
```

You have the line:

```js
const check = await client.verify.services(verify)
```

In the blog post this is:

```js
client.verify.services(process.env.VERIFY_SERVICE_SID);
```

So, you have replaced the verify service sid with a non-existant `verify` variable. Go back and make sure you have `VERIFY_SERVICE_SID` set in your `.env` file and then change the code back to the original, and then you should be good to go!

Comment: I changed it to send-verification but got these errors instead: https://imgur.com/a/5BjvcVQ

Comment: Did you see an error in your terminal where you're running the express app now? You're now making a request to the right endpoint but your app is refusing them for some reason.

Comment: In my terminal I got: sh-3.2$ node index.js
Server started at http://localhost:3000
/Users/username/Downloads/keep_out-3/verify-sms-express/index.js:17
  client.verify.services(verify)
                         ^

ReferenceError: verify is not defined

Comment: I've updated my answer with further detail. Please check and try again.